# Oauth regenerateIdentityCallback not working

Tags: oauth, owin

I'm using oauth and owin for my authentication in my app.
i want to regenerate identity with new claims in an interval but the method assigned to it's function handler is never been called
here is my code:

```
  public static void ConfigureCookieAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {

                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, PouyaKianParham.ContentProviderSystem.BusinessObjectLayer.Account.Models.ApplicationUser, int>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),

                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (a, b) => GenerateUserIdentityAsync(null,null),
                        getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))

            },

            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")

        });

    }
```

And here is my callback method(which is also in OAuthconfig.cs):

```
       public static async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager ApplicationUserManager, UserManager manager)
    {
        //regenrating identity with new claims
        return identitywithClaim;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, but the following worked for me.
I use a custom implementation of UserStore, UserManager and so on. It turned out, that the UserStore has to implement `IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser, in TKey>`.
 
After it was implemented, the `regenerateIdentityCallback` delegate is called when needed and everything works beautifully.

Comment: thank you for your answer i will give it a try and will notify you with the result :)

Comment: This was exactly what has causing my issue.